why poi.emergency doesn't work in javascript map api
I want to color some geometry using API, but I found some of the geometry didn't work like what it is on the cloud style editing webpage. For exameple, below I want to color the poi.emergency, but it just color the whole map instead of color the selected geometry.
function initMap() {
  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
  // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  const styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    [
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "land",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{ color: "#a5b076" }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.emergency",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{color: "#00bfff"}]
      },
     { name: "LandUse" },
    ]
  );
  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
  // to the map type control.
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 55.647, lng: 37.581 },
    zoom: 13,
    //mapId: "38041c807200bb37",
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [],
    },
    
  });

  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set("LandUse", styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId("LandUse");
}

window.initMap = initMap;

see if you encouter the same case....

Could you please raise an issue in Google Public Issue Tracker?
